# Laravel with SQLite Migration Errors

Tags: laravel, sqlite

When I try to run `php artisan migrate` I get the following errors

```
Connection.php line 664:                                                                                                                                                                               
could not find driver (SQL: select * from sqlite_master where type = 'table' and name = migrations) 

PDOConnection.php line 31:                                                                                                                                                                             
could not find driver                                                                                                                                                                                   

PDOConnection.php line 27:                                                                         
could not find driver
```

When I try to load Laravel (just for testing connection to the DB) I get the following error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: options (SQL: select * from "options" where "key" = live_stream limit 1)
```

my .env configuration is

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=d:\www\dma-laravel\database\database.sqlite3
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I have tested my systems ability to connect to the database file with an external test and my system can open the problem no problem.

From looking at the two different errors from Laravel and PHP Artisan it appears to me Laravel is seeing and attempting to open the database with no problem. However, PHP Artisan can not connect to the database.

What am I missing? Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Artisan runs PHP on command line. You might accidentally be running a different PHP version/setup on command line compared to the webserver. Could that be the problem?

Comment: My php info file says 7.4.5 while php -v says 7.2.9. How is that even possible and how do I sort the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP command line binary is probably different from the PHP you are using with your webserver. It's a common issue. You can have multiple PHP versions on your system.

A quick solution would be to just also install the SQLite PHP driver for the PHP version on the command line.

If you want to use a different PHP version on command line, then changing that depends on your operating system and on how you installed PHP.

Comment: I am running Windows and I am a bit confused as to how I have 2 different versions installed. I thought I only had one installed.

Comment: Almost immediately I realized the command line tool might be able to tell me where the PHP version it was seeing by using ```which php```. I turns out it was using the version of PHP installed with Laragon. While my web server was using the version I installed into Windows. I am not running this site in Laragon but rather Valet. So the confusion was in the command line tool I was using.